# invoke the responder class from flash media server

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a question to invoke the responder method defined in a flash client within an asynchronous function defined in a flash media server.

my client code,

> private function handleResp
>   (result:Object) {    trace ("get the
>   number " + result.number); }
>
> netConnection.call ("getnum", new
>   Responder (handleResp));

my server code,

> Application.handleServerResp.onResult
>   = function (result) 
>   {
>
> **//?????? how to invoke the client's handleResp**

}

> >
>
> Client.prototype.getnum = function ()
>   {
>
> // cannot get the number, call another
>   server (central one) for the number
>
> centralNetConnection.call
>   ("getnumNOW", new Responder
>   (handleServerResp)); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the Responder class is used to handle the return value of a server method, so you can't use it asynchronously.
You can do this:

Create a client responder method (it should be public, otherwise FMS can't reach it).

```
    public function handleResp (result:Object) { trace ("get the number " + result.number); };
```

Set the client of the NetConnection object.

```
    netConnection.client = this; // if your responder function is in this scope, otherwise set that object what contains your function.
```

Call the server side method.

```
    netConnection.call ("getnum", null); // set null as resopnder
```

In your responder method on the server side, call the client side method.

```
    Application.handleServerResp.onResult = function (result) 
    {
        clientOBJ.call( "handleResp", null, result ); // you don't use responder, so pass null as second parameter
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Tamas Gronas

Comment: @Tamas, this is exactly what I did. Thanks for your response.